# Relational or objectrelational model while using Oracle?

Tags: oracle, database-design, ordbms

I have created a database in Oracle SQL Developer and was wondering what kind of model it is. I have read in several books that Oracle supports a relational model and introduced features for objectrelational databases in the 90s. Now I am not quite sure what model I have implemented. Actually, I am not using objectrelational stuff like CLOB/ BLOB or something else, so I would say that I have implemented a relational model.

Is that correct?

Comment: CLOBs and BLOBs are just files at the end of the day - or data types as far as your Oracle SCHEMA cares about. Have you gone and created any TYPEs? https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADOBJ/adobjbas.htm#ADOBJ7068

Comment: No I haven't created any own types. I have just created my tables and using the usual data types that Oracle provides.

Comment: CLOB/BLOBs have nothing to do with "object relational stuff".

Comment: If you don't know if you've created a object-relational schema or not, then you probably haven't. Now the next question, is it relational? Do you have relations in your logical or FK in your physical design?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Hm, I think in an indirect way they have to do something with object - relational models, because Oracle introduced that kind of datatype together with the other object-relational concepts. So that's actually what I have read in several books. Furthermore it is mentioned that a disadvantage of relational models is the storage. That means that a varchar is restricted to 4000 characters for example. CLOB and BLOB solve that problem.

Comment: No, CLOB/BLOB have absolutely nothing to do with object relational features. It's just a coincidence that they were introduced in the same release that introduced the first object relational features (those types are part of the SQL standard by the way, which does not even mention any object relational features)

Comment: @thatjeffsmith: Yes, I have defined several constraints and foreign keys in my table. And that probably is  a hint that I have created a relational model and not a object-relational model because then I would have object identities.

Comment: The "relational model" does not restrict the length of a varchar in any way. It's a technical restriction of the implementation of the SQL language in a specific DBMS product. And this limitation is also very product specific. Postgres for example - which is also an object relational database  - has no limitation of 4000 bytes for a varchar column (it's limited to 1GB)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oracle also has no limit of 4000 bytes for a varchar column

Comment: @thatjeffsmith: it had such a restriction up to Oracle 11 and it's still the default behaviour when you do a fresh install. You are right that you _can_ increase that limit to 32k nowadays.

Comment: You can have a look at the official documentation of oracle about the datatypes here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i54330